# Memory Space Layout / strange memory (stack) behaviour C/ASM?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, assembly, stack

When playing around with memory to get a better understanding of the process memory layout and the behind the scenes in general I failed to comprehend it entirely. Imagine the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv) {
    char buf[32];
    strcpy(buf,argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Dump from `IDA` (`dec` not `hex`):

**Added**

```
var_30= dword ptr -30h
var_2C= dword ptr -2Ch
var_20= dword ptr -20h
arg_4= dword ptr  0Ch
```

**End**

```
push    ebp
mov     ebp, esp
and     esp, 4294967280
sub     esp, 48
call    sub_401920
mov     eax, [ebp+12]
add     eax, 4
mov     eax, [eax]
mov     [esp+4], eax
lea     eax, [esp+16]
mov     [esp], eax
call    strcpy
mov     eax, 0
leave
retn
```

My interpretation:

- 1) Pushes `EBP` onto the stack
- 2) Aligns `ESP` with `EBP`
- 3) `and esp, 4294967280` compiler pattern can probably be ignored (?)
- 4) Substract 48 bytes from `ESP` allocating 48 bytes in size
- N) The compiler I used inefficiently allocates memory by blocks of 16 bytes, i.e. if you have a single integer it will allocate 16 bytes, if you go over 16 it will use 32, 48, 64 and so on
- 5) Call to function related to the compiler pattern in (3) can probably be ignored (?)

Since `EBP+0x0-0x3` stores the `EBP` pointer and `EBP+0x4-0x7` the return address we can sort of see what's going on here.

- 1) Move the pointer `argv` into `EAX`
- 2) Add 4 bytes to `EAX` (now points to `EBP+12+4`)
- 3) Move the pointer `EBP+12+4` into `EAX`
- N) `EBP+12+4` would be equal to `argv[1]`
- 4) Moves the pointer of `argv[1]` onto the stack `ESP+4`
- 5) ???
- 6) Stores content of `buf[32]` on ESP+0 (?)

The question, even though, very appreciated if answered, is not so much the `ASM` but rather:

To my understanding the stack frame of this function should look like this:

```
[   ] < ESP+0x0-0x3 
[   ]
[   ]
[   ]
[   ]
[   ]
[   ]
[   ]
[   ]
[   ]
[   ]
[   ] < ESP+0x2C-0x2F
[EBP] < EBP+0x0-0x3
[RET] < EBP+0x4-0x7
[ARG]
```

Where `ARG` (EBP+0x8+) contains the functions' argument(s).

**Confusion**

- When I used 44 bytes of data `A` as user input it caused a stack overflow while there is only 4 other bytes for the `argv[1]` pointer on the stack so where does the single byte come from?
- `EBP` is 4 bytes as it is a pointer however when I used 45 bytes of data entire `EBP` was already overwritten with A's.
- `EIP` (afaik) is controlled by overwriting `EBP+0x3-0x7` (RET) and is also 4 bytes in size. However, 46 bytes of data resulted in `EIP` being rewritten halfway by A's, 47 bytes 3/4th, and 48 bytes fully overwrote `EIP` with A's

Finally, is there any reason why when sending a much too big buffer `EIP` is no longer rewritten? Is that because it starts overwriting the previous stack frame resulting in a much earlier crash course?

Comment: This looks like an extremely poor way of analysing the compiler behavior. Just make the compiler emit the assembly (e.g. `gcc -S`) with symbols and labels. Half the code you show is the pre-main setup.

Comment: @KerrekSB I'm not trying to analyze compiler behaviour. I'm trying to analyze the process memory layout and stack behaviour.

Comment: What do think determines the process's memory layout and stack behaviour? The assembly code your looking at was generated by a compiler. Understanding the code means understanding why the compiler generated that code. What you're doing is trying to analyze the behaviour of the compiler. In any case the question you're asking isn't clear. It doesn't help that you're inappropriately using the names of registers to refer to locations on the stack.

Comment: IDA has a debugger you can use to single-step through the assembly instructions and observe their effects on the stack and registers. Do so, and a lot of these questions will get answered.

Comment: @RossRidge How am I inappropriately using names of registers to refer to the location on the stack? It generated that code because I told it to. The questions are why, if I overflow the 32 byte buffer on the stack with 12 bytes (44 total) and there is but one other pointer on the stack of size 4, yet, the memory allocated is 48 bytes causes a stack overflow? Why does EBP get entirely rewritten to 0x41414141 - 1 byte after the stack overflow even though it's a 4 byte datatype? Why does EIP get rewritten to 0x00004141 from an other 1 byte? That is confusing behaviour to me.

Comment: EIP is a register that can't be changed except through program control instructions (JMP, CALL, RET, etc...) and the normal advancement of the program counter after executing an instruction. It can't be rewritten "from an other 1 byte". What you apparently mean is not EIP, but the the memory location where the return address is stored on the stack. Assuming that's true that still leaves the question of what do you mean "from an other 1 byte"? What other byte? I could go on like this pointing out things that are unclear about your question, but I've run out of room in this comment.

Comment: @RossRidge Well, the Q has been answered below. Your idea of what was going on went wrong the moment you disagreed with me on what I was asking. Again, I said I was analyzing the memory layout and stack behaviour not compiler behaviour; you said "No". Apparently, you're so full of yourself that you think you know better what I'm asking than I. _Weird_.

 User input has a serious effect on what happens on memory level, you can change EIP by overwriting the RET address on the stack as seen above when you i.e. overflow certain datatypes, access pointer after deallocated memory region, etc, etc.

Comment: If I thought I understood your question I wouldn't have tried to explain twice how your question was unclear. The sad thing is that even after user781847's answer below that painstakingly tried to explain what the compiler was doing (ie. compiler behaviour), even after you've had over a year and half to learn how CPUs and compilers work, you're still just as wilfully ignorant as you were when you asked the question. It's not me who's full of themselves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's analyze that code

```
push    ebp
mov     ebp, esp
```

This is a standard prolog.

```
and     esp, 0ffffffff0h
```

The low nibble (4 bits) of `ESP` are cleared. This, in the worst case, lower the stack pointer by 15 bytes and in the best by nothing.
However this operation align the stack on 16 byte boundaries. This behavior has increased recently (when I started looking at disassembled binaries no compiler aligned the stack) and it is due the increasing use of the *SSE* and *AVX* instructions.

```
sub     esp, 30h
```

Here the space for local vars is allocated. In theory you have 32 bytes of locals, so 20h bytes. 
Here the compiler do something really cleaver. It notices that `strcpy` takes two 4 byte params. So instead of using two `push` instruction it allocated space
for that params directly here.
To keep the stack aligned it need to reach a multiple of 16. It cannot simply reserve 28h bytes, it reserves instead 30h bytes. Wasting 8 bytes is not a great loss for the sake of an aligned stack pointer.
So the space allocated is

```
EBP         <-- Old Frame Pointer (Saved EBP)
...
EBP - 20h   <-- Start of 32 byte array (Up to EBP-01h included)
EBP - 24h   <-- Unused
EBP - 28h   <-- Unused
EBP - 2ch   <-- strcpy source ptr
EBP - 30h   <-- strcpy destination ptr
```

**In this picture I intentionally left out the stack alignment operation at the beginning of the prolog in order to have definite offsets and for the sake of clarity**.
Next instruction is

```
call    sub_401920
```

Hard to tell without symbols of full disassembly but this is likely the CRT initialization. What is called `__main` in GCC assembled sources.

`main` takes two params: `argc` and `argv`. The memory layout *above* `EBP` is:

```
...
EBP + 0ch    <-- argv
EBP + 08h    <-- argc
EBP + 04h    <-- Return address
EBP          <-- Previous Frame Pointer (Saved EBP)
EBP - 04h    <-- Locals (Array)
EBP - 08h    <-- Locals (Array)
...
```

The next instructions just load `argv[1]`

```
mov     eax, [ebp+0ch]        ;<-- argv ptr
add     eax, 4                ;<-- &argv[1]
mov     eax, [eax]            ;<-- argv[1]
mov     [esp+4], eax          ;<-- Like a push
```

Remember that when the last instruction is executed the stack pointer is just
below the local area

```
...
EBP - 20h   <-- Start of 32 byte array (Up to EBP-01h included)
EBP - 24h   <-- Unused
EBP - 28h   <-- Unused
EBP - 2ch   <-- ESP+04h (strcpy source ptr)
EBP - 30h   <-- STACK POINTER (strcpy destination ptr)
```

The same thing for the destination

```
lea     eax, [esp+10h]    ;Pointer to ebp-20h (EAX = ebp-20h)
mov     [esp], eax        ;Like a push
call    strcpy
```

And finally the standard epilog

```
mov     eax, 0
leave
retn
```

Now it's time to get the full picture with the stack alignment. Aligning the stack lower the stack pointer after the `EBP` register has been saved. Referencing local vars is done trough `ESP` mostly.

```
      +---------+
      |  argv   |  EBP + 0ch
      +---------+
      |  argc   |  EBP + 08h
      +---------+
      | ret adr |  EBP + 04h
      +---------+
EBP ->| Old EBP |  EBP
      +---------+
      | Unused  |  EBP - 04h    \
          ...                    > Variable length (min: 0, max = 0fh)
      | Unused  |  ESP + 30h    /
      +---------+
      |  Array  |  
          ...
      |  Array  |  ESP + 10h 
      +---------+
      | Unused  |  ESP + 0ch
      +---------+
      | Unused  |  ESP + 08h
      +---------+
      | src ptr |  ESP + 04h
      +---------+
ESP ->| dst ptr |  ESP
      +---------+
```

---

**Regarding your final questions, it is not possible to answer deterministically.**
If the compiler were not aligning the stack the answers would be:

1. When you input 44 bytes, you stard writing it at `EBP-20h` so there are 12 exceeding bytes. You overwrite first the old frame pointer, then the return address and then the `argc` value.
2. `EBP` is 4 bytes because it is 32 bit register. With 45 bytes you overwrite the old frame pointer (`EBP`) saved on the stack. See above.
3. You start overwriting the return address with 37 bytes of data (requiring 40 byte to fully overwrite).

However by aligning the stack pointer you are effectively lowering the `ESP` by a variable (in theory) amount of data and so the number above must be added with a variable number between 0 and 15. So for example it seem that the aligning in your case lowered the stack pointer by 7 bytes in the last question.

Comment: Very thorough explanation. I think i'll be able to figure out the questions I had using this visualization! Thank you!